# CSS selector for a disabled and checked radio button's label

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using C# .net
I have a situation where I have a few pre-checked and disabled radio button lists on my screen.
What I want is for checked and disabled radio buttons the text should be green and bold 
for that I have written the following CSS class

```
 input[type="radio"]:disabled  +label 
 {
     color: Gray;
 } 
 input[type="radio"]:checked  +label 
 {
     font-weight: bold; 
     color: Green;
 }
 input[type="radio"]:enabled  +label 
 {
     color: Black;
     font-weight: normal;
 }
```

This is working fine for firefox, IE9, and chrome.
the issue comes when I try it in IE 8 and low.. 
that time the css does not get applied.
Is there any way to apply the same effect for IE 6, 7 and 8??
P.S. I can't use jquery or javascript for this.. the only viable option is by using css

Comment: any other ways in css to achieve this/

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# or .NET.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Except for the `:enabled` pseudo selector, you can achieve the same result with CSS2 `attribute selectors` and have it working just fine with IE7 and above:

```
 input[type="radio"][disabled] + label 
 {
     color: Gray;
 } 

 input[type="radio"][checked] + label 
 {
     font-weight: bold; 
     color: Green;
 }
```

Some would argue that the `:enabled` selector is redudant, and is actually the default style for `input[type=radio] + label` when no `disabled/checked` attributes defined.

Comment: Well.. the disabled part worked fine for IE 7 and 8 also.. but is there an alternate available for [checked] in IE7???